# Am I over promising with the following code?

Tags: javascript, promise

The code works but I'm wondering if I'm *over promising*.

I have this Redux Action

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';
const uploadAsynch = Promise.promisify(api.upload);

uploadFiles : function(data, dispatch){
    var data = {
      ep:"EP_UPLOAD",
      payload: {
       files: data.files,
       profile: data.profile
      }
    }
    uploadAsynch(data).then((result)=>{
      dispatch({type: FILES_UPLOADED})
    });
  },
```

api.upload is the following

```
import axios from 'axios';

upload : function(data, callback){
    var files = new FormData();
    for(var i=0; i<data.payload.files.length; i++){
      files.append('files', data.payload.files[i], data.payload.files[i].name);
    }
    axios.post(apiEndpoints[data.ep], files, {
      headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=--*`,
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      callback(null, response)
    }).catch((error) => {
      callback(error)
    });
  },
```

So I'm wondering. If Axios is a promise based request client is it correct to wrap it with bluebird in the action?

Comment: What do you mean by *over promising*? Do you really need `upload` to be callback-based?

Comment: That is what I wonder... Should it just be a return and then handle with a switch that response?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “with a switch” either. If you don’t need your `api.upload` to be callback-based, though, it’s probably best to make it just return a promise, yes.

Comment: So in the action I would just have `api.upload(data)` and then api.upload just returns true or error depending on what axios gets as response from the server? Where do I fire the `dispatch` from? From within the axios upload function?

Comment: `api.upload` just works exactly the same as `uploadAsynch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you're under-promising, because you don't use promises to their full capability. However, you do fall back to callbacks and at the same time promisify that function again, which is pretty pointless. Just `return` the promise you had in the first place.

```
// no promisification
uploadFiles: function(data, dispatch){
  var data = {
    ep:"EP_UPLOAD",
    payload: {
      files: data.files,
      profile: data.profile
    }
  }
  return api.upload(data).then(result =>
//^^^^^^
    dispatch({type: FILES_UPLOADED})
  );
}
```

```
import axios from 'axios';

upload: function(data) { // no callback
  var files = new FormData();
  for (var i=0; i<data.payload.files.length; i++){
    files.append('files', data.payload.files[i], data.payload.files[i].name);
  }
  return axios.post(apiEndpoints[data.ep], files, {
//^^^^^^
    headers: {
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
      'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=--*`,
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: v interesting. I thought that a promise's chain is tied to it but from your example, which works, it seems like I can apply the chain one level above (from where i call the promise). Is that correct to say? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what "a promise's chain" means to you. A chain always consists of *multiple* promises, and it can't be "tied" to something. How [`then` returns new promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) is the real magic - and yes, promises are *values* that can be passed around and be `return`ed from functions like any other, it doesn't matter when/where/whether the `.then()` method is called on it.